# Get the name of all the tables on my database

Tags: symfony, propel

I need get the name of all the tables that exist on my database. I am usin Propel like my ORM. Actully i have been trying on this form.

```
$dbmap = \Propel::getDatabaseMap('data');
    $tablastmp = $dbmap->getTables();
    $tablas = array();
    foreach ($tablastmp as $tablatmp) {
        $tablas[] = $tablatmp->getName();
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($tablas);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
```

but this return an array that is empty.

array();

And I need that return something like that:

```
array( [0] => 'clients', [1] => 'workers' );
```

Please someone help. I have been trying that for a few days.

Comment: And if you do a `var_dump($tablastmp)` what it returns ?

Comment: If you try with `getTableMap()` method like it is explain here : [Doc propel](http://propelorm.org/cookbook/runtime-introspection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you probably wouldn't use Propel to get this information as Propel only loads the table map information when the table is actually used.

The original Schema file is used during the build phase (running 'propel_gen om' etc).  The runtime part of Propel never looks at the Schema file, so there is no way to query it per se.

The answer to your question is to look at the database, e.g. the MySQL query to list the tables in a database:
    SHOW [FULL] TABLES [{FROM | IN} db_name]
         [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]

Answer (score -1):

This might help you (hopefully)

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
foreach ($em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata() as $md) {
    var_dump($md->getName()); // dump the full class names
    var_dump($md->getTableName()); // dump the table names
}
```

Comment: thanks for the intention, but I cant aplicate that, because I am using propel.